# NoClassDefFoundError when using iText

Tags: java, itext, noclassdeffounderror

I'm getting this NoClassDefFoundError when I try to make a pdf using iText.
My code (It's the same code as from the site.):

```
        String input = "C:\\input.jpg";
        String output = "output.pdf";
        PdfWriter pdfWriter;
        try {
            pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(output);
            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
            Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
            ImageData data = ImageDataFactory.create(input);
            Image image = new Image(data);
            doc.add(image);
            doc.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Error code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfCatalog.<clinit>(PdfCatalog.java:73)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.open(PdfDocument.java:1963)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:285)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:266)
    at Test.f(Test.java:127)
    at Test.run(Test.java:34)
    at Main.main(Main.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: That's a typical problem I faced. If you use maven/gradle, make sure only one version of itext is required by any dependencies. You may have had your expected version overriden by a transitive dependency requirement.

Comment: Are you using maven? If so, try running: mvn dependency:tree and look at the list to see if it includes the needed iText dependencies. If not, add them to your pom.xml.